# mule customizing the logger with flows

Tags: mule

I have four flows each is having http end point:

```
<flow1 >
<http:myhosts:port path="test1">
</flow1>
<flow2>
<http:myhosts:port path="test2">
</flow2>
<flow3>
<http:myhosts:port path="test3">
</flow3>
<flow4>
<http:myhosts:port path="test4">
</flow1>
```

I am using mule 3.5, have defined log4j.properties as

```
log = /tmp
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${log}/mylogs.log
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'ddMMyyyy
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender    
log4j.appender.console.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

It prints logger in tmp directory with a single file name.

What I need to make is, for each flow or url, mule have to create logfiles as  test1-12:20:00(present-time).log
So If I run 4 flows, then I need to have 4 logger files should be created as

```
test1-12:20:00(present-time).log
test1-13:20:00(present-time).log
test1-14:20:00(present-time).log
test1-15:20:00(present-time).log
```

How do I make this? Is this possible to do in Mule configuration?

Comment: I don't think this is possible to do in Mule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could accomplish this using categories.

First, create four separate appenders in log4j.  For Mule 3.5, you may continue using the properties configuration but keep in mind you will have to go to XML configuration in Mule 3.6 because of the move to log4j2.

```
log4j.appender.thing1=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.thing1.File=/var/log/integration/Thing1/mylogs.log
# etc...
log4j.appender.thing2=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.thing2.File=/var/log/integration/Thing2/mylogs.log
# etc...
```

Then, define loggers for specific categories like so:

```
log4j.logger.com.mycompany.Thing1=DEBUG,thing1
log4j.logger.com.mycompany.Thing2=DEBUG,thing2
# etc...
```

Finally, add loggers in your flows that use the appropriate category:

```
<flow name="Thing1">
    <!-- your flow logic goes here -->
    <logger category="com.mycompany.Thing1" message="Something happened" level="INFO" />
    <!-- more flow logic goes here -->
</flow>

<flow name="Thing2">
    <!-- your other flow logic goes here -->
    <logger category="com.mycompany.Thing2" message="Something happened in flow 2" level="INFO" />
    <!-- more flow logic goes here -->
</flow>
```

Note that when you move to 3.6 and begin using log4j2, you will be able to take advantage of the more flexible [RollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender) and have greater control over when rolling happens and how the file names are generated.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do that in just with log4j without a lot of work. However you could prepend your logger messages with `#[flow.name]`.